# Gradle+Libgdx+GooglePlayService, cant they co-exist in peace?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx, google-play-services

I've been trying to add googlePlayService library to my Libgdx Game project, I followed these two pages:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13442&hilit=play+services
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples
It compiles without errors. However, when I try to "import com.google.*" into my core Game project it doesn't recognize it. I tried to "import com.google.*" into the utils project, and eclipse recognizes it, and gives me a list to choose from.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you want to import google play services into the core project? Google play services is for android only.

Comment: I read that I can use google play services on desktop as well. Anyway, that is not the main issue here right now. I tried to access com.google.* from android project, and failed. How do I get it to work>

Comment: Hm, with some hacks it may be possible to integrate in desktop as well, but I am not aware that google play services officially supports desktop apps as well now. Anyhow, it would still be platform-dependent as it will be different from Android & iOS, so I wouldn't put it in core project ;-) About your integration in android project: Did you add the gradle dependencies and refreshed gradle dependencies?

Comment: I see. So I'm guessing that debugging the google play services MUST be done using either a virtual/real android device, right?

Answer (score 0):

Android->Properties->Java Build Path->Add Library->Choose "BaseGameUtils"(or utils like in the forum)
Fixed the problem.